# The cleanest way of creating an empty folder structure

Tags: c#, file-io, directory-structure

I'm fairly new to C# (but very motivated) so please bear with me. I'm coding in C# directly in Grasshopper at the moment (later on I will probably move it out of there and write in VS, but not for now). I want to create a folder structure with some empty folders and some folders with text files, which I later on want to write to.

So with help of Google I managed to do this but I'm not convinced that this is the best/cleanest/most efficient way of doing this.

Could someone give me some critic here please :)

cheers,
David.

```
string folderPath = @"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Folder";

string firstSubFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, "firstSubFolder");
string secondSubFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, "secondSubFolder");

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(firstSubFolderPath);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(secondSubFolderPath);

string subSubFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(firstSubFolderPath, "subSubFolder");
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subSubFolderPath);
string firstTextFile = "firstTextFile.txt";
string secondTextFile = "secondTextFile.txt";

firstTextFile= System.IO.Path.Combine(subSubFolderPath, firstTextFile);
secondTextFile= System.IO.Path.Combine(secondSubFolderPath, secondTextFile);

using (StreamWriter firstWriter = new StreamWriter(firstTextFile));
using (StreamWriter secondWriter = new StreamWriter(secondTextFile));
```

Comment: I'd use `using (File.Create(firstTextFile));` to create the empty file. It'll do the exact same thing, but it better expresses the intent

Comment: There is no need to create directory if you need to create subdirectory. CreateDirectory creates folder hierarchy for the given path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You only need to create the lowest level of the directory tree. The `CreateDirectory` method will create all directories in the path that don't yet exist.

Comment: Also, if this is all a fixed structure of directories/files, you might consider just creating a zip file with this structure and expanding that into the root.

Comment: I'd use DirectoryInfo and FileInfo to create Directory/File. you can check with [DirectoryInfo].Exists and [FileInfo].Exists and after that you can also create new one.

Comment: also, you can make directoryinfo from fileinfo with [fileinfo].Directory

Comment: Well the code is not that bad for a first try. If you are creating file and somewhere down the line you want to test `Delete` to delete one of the directory you just have created. Even if you just want to simply the clean up between test. Please do your self a favor and insert a clean usb drive. Change your path to this usb drive and play test on it. It will be easier to clean between 2 test. And you won't delete your user profile etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) class, you can use a sort of fluent syntax, which may be more readible.

This code creates the first folder and its subfolder and returns its path, which you can then use to create the text files.

```
    var folderPath = @"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Folder";

    var subsubfolder = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
        .CreateSubdirectory("subfolder")
        .CreateSubdirectory("subsubfolder")
        .FullName;
```

Comment: This looks neat, do you know if this works directly in Grasshopper? I tried it out but didn't get it to work.